# How to select CollectionView cell in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I need to select the item at specific index in collection view using RxSwift.This method is not working fine.

```
 collectionView.rx.modelSelected(SearchResult.self).subscribe(onNext:{ menuItem in }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Where are you declaring the disposeBag?

Comment: Outside the ViewDidLoad()

Comment: When you say it is "not working fine" what does that mean? Does anything happen? If so, what happens? -- Have you checked via breakpoint if `menuItem` had the correct value based on what cell you clicked?

Comment: You can try debugging it using the `debug` operator - just add before the `.subscribe` this:
`.debug("RX: Model selected")` and see whats going on behind the scene (is it being subscribed? maybe more then once? maybe its being disposed before it has the chance to emit anything)

Comment: According to the RxCocoa docs `modelSelected(:)` can only be used if the table is populated using one of the `rx.items` overloads.  Are you using one of those overloads?  Another thing to check is that the table's delegate isn't being set in your code.

Answer (score 38):

If you want the indexPath of item selected you can use the following :

```
collectionView
    .rx
    .itemSelected
        .subscribe(onNext:{ indexPath in
            //your code
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and if you want to the model being selected :

```
collectionView
        .rx
        .modelSelected(SearchResult.self)
        .subscribe(onNext: { (model) in
            //Your code
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And you can combine the above, to get the modelSelected with their indexPath as follow:

```
  Observable
            .zip(
                collectionView
                    .rx
                    .itemSelected
                ,collectionView
                    .rx
                    .modelSelected(SearchResult.self)
            )
            .bind{ [unowned self] indexPath, model in

            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Building off of mojtaba al moussawi's answer, I made an extension to make the zipping easy:

```
extension Reactive where Base: UICollectionView {
    public func modelAndIndexSelected<T>(_ modelType: T.Type) -> ControlEvent<(T, IndexPath)> {
        ControlEvent(events: Observable.zip(
            self.modelSelected(modelType),
            self.itemSelected
        ))
    }
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
collectionView
    .rx
    .modelAndIndexSelected(SearchResult.self)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (model, index) in
        //Your code
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```