# Selecting UICollectionViewCell in the presence of UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I am trying to respond to `UICollectionViewCell` selection:

```
private func setupCellAction() {
    collectionView?.rx.itemSelected
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath in
            print("itemSelected!")
            let cell = self?.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CellTypeCollectionViewCell
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBarchartSegue", sender: cell)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

But somehow `onNext` method is never called. I tried putting `setupCellAction()` in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` but it is not working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried the suggestion from the following thread: [How to select CollectionView cell in RxSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323645/how-to-select-collectionview-cell-in-rxswift)

and added `.debug("RX: Model selected")` before the `subscribe` method. I see the output in the console that it is subscribed once.

> Update

I tried rewriting the `setupCellAction()` in the following way:

```
private func setupCellAction() {
    collectionView?.rx.modelSelected(CellTypeCollectionViewCell.self)
        .asObservable()
        .debug("RX: Model selected")
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] cell in
            print("itemSelected!")
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBarchartSegue", sender: cell)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

It is not working either. I see also that it is subscribed once in the console.

> Update

`UICollectionViewController` was embedded in another container `UIViewController`, and in it I defined `UITapGestureRecognizer`. After commenting out the code for the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, the `itemSelected()` method started to work. Right now I need a way to let the tap event through if it happened on the `UICollectionViewCell`. Is there a way to do that?

The code for tapping in the container controller (`viewDidLoad`):

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

The `handleTap():`

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    tableView.isHidden = true
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: When did you set up delegate?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, which delegate?

Comment: I am not sure. If you set delegate it may override itemSelected event.

Comment: With GestureRecognizer it does. So, I need a way to avoid this thing when user clicks on the cells, but not anywhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let taps through with the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol and implementing the method
`func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool`.

Basically, you need to return `false` whenever you touch a `UICollectionViewCell`, if I understood the problem correctly.

You can do this by using the method `func indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?` from the UICollectionView. If the given CGPoint matches a cell's location, you will get its IndexPath.

Don't forget to translate the touch location to the collection view's frame - you can use UITouch's `func location(in view: UIView?) -> CGPoint` for this.

It would probably look somewhat like this:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let point = touch.location(in: collectionView)
    return collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point) == nil
}
```